# Consumer vs Enterprise SSD

Tags: storage, database, ssd, provisioning

I'm deciding what SSD's to use in our infrastructure. Enterprise drives are obviously more reliable but storage items are expendable and will fail anyway. So considering that we have proper RAID, backup and fail-over solutions in place what would you suggest to buy?

I tend to think that in general it is better to buy cheap stuff with lots of spares and just replace them when they break. For the price of Enterprise level SSD I can buy many consumer SSD's.

Comment: Use what's supported by your hardware. Without specifics on brand and models or the applications and use-case, this isn't a very good question.

Answer (score 3):

`I tend to think that in general it is better to buy cheap stuff with lots of spares and just replace them when they break` - I guess I don't understand that line of thinking. Should you be financially frugal? Yes. Should you be cheap? Probably not. I don't have any expertise on the specifics of consumer versus enterprise SSD drives so I can't speak to that directly, but the idea that you consider `going cheap` as a viable and acceptable practice for your enterprise infrastructure seems shortsighted and foolish to me. How important to the business is the data that lives on these drives? How important to the business are the services that the servers where these cheap drives reside provide? Is it really prudent to `go cheap`? How much downtime can the business tolerate if you have a loss of service due to these cheap drives? That doesn't sound like a career sustaining course of action to me.